# Ruby on Rails: No API response body after accessing ActionController::API in an initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller

I am trying to implement a custom logging gem (heavily based on [lograge](https://github.com/roidrage/lograge)).

In a method that gets called from an initializer, I have some logic to add to the payload that is passed to the `process_action.action_controller` event, which looks something like:

```rb
def self.add_custom_payload
  base_classes = [ActionController::Base, ActionController::API]
  base_classes.each do |base_class|
    # logic that adds stuff to payload
  end
end
```

After adding this, when I make any requests to my API (the app that I am using to test this with makes use of `ActionController::API`), I always get an empty body in response. The HTTP status code and headers are as expected.

I assumed that it was something to do with the logic that I am using to add stuff to the payload, but turns out it's not. Even if I remove everything else, and literally just have

```rb
def self.add_custom_payload
  ActionController::API
end
```

in the method that gets called from the initializer, the same thing happens, and all requests return an empty response body.

I am stumped. What is causing this?

TL;DR: If I access `ActionController::API` in an initializer, all responses have an empty body.

Comment: Any reason you are not leveraging `append_info_to_payload`. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Instrumentation.html

Comment: Or just creating a piece of middleware and putting it between the router and controller.